# Turn paragraph entries into columns with posix awk or sed?

Tags: arrays, awk, sed, scripting, posix

I'm parsing a file that looks like this:

```
Al Bronson
Bud Collins
Yousef Zane

2020-03-04
2020-04-04
2018-05-14

Actor 8
Stage 3
Producer 2
```

And I want them formatted into this:

```
Al Bronson,2020-03-04,Actor 8
Bud Collins,2020-04-04,Stage 3
Yousef Zane,2018-05-14,Producer 2
```

---

I've tried

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    FS = "\n"
    RS = "" 
    OFS = "," 
    ORS = "\n" 
  }
  {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
      arr[$i] = $i
    }
  }
  END {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
      print arr[$i]
  }' \
"$FILE"
```

But it just outputs

```
Actor 8
Stage 3
Producer 2
```

---

And whats weird is that this:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    FS = "\n"
    RS = "" 
    OFS = "," 
    ORS = "\n" 
  }
  {
    print $1
  }' \
"$FILE"
```

Outputs something close to what I want:

```
Al Bronson
2020-03-04
Actor 8
```

I'm at wits end b/c it seems so easy and -- I think -- I'm close!

Can someone explain what going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` is a number, while `$i` is the content of the i-th field, so `arr[i]` and not `arr[$i]` is the syntax you want. Also you have to append the new field, not assign and overwrite existing content. So your script should be:

```
BEGIN {
    FS = "\n"
    RS = "" 
    OFS = "," 
    ORS = "\n" 
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        arr[i] = (arr[i]? arr[i] OFS $i: $i)
    }
}
END {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        print arr[i]
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Scales perfectly and explained my mess up :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume the input consists of three records and each record has the same number of fields (lines). The script below reads these three records and splits each record on newlines.

```
awk -F'\n' -v RS= -v OFS=, '
    NR == 1 { n = split($0, names) }
    NR == 2 { split($0, dates) }
    NR == 3 { split($0, info) }
    END     { for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) print names[i], dates[i], info[i] }
' file
```